# Error using salmon with nextflow with docker on Macbook m1

Tags: docker, apple-m1, nextflow

I've been try to run a simple pipeline with nextflow and docker for practice.

Here is my dockerfile which create a container with salmon, the tool i'm using in nextflow :

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN curl -sSL https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon/releases/download/v1.5.2/salmon-1.5.2_linux_x86_64.tar.gz | tar xz \
&& mv /salmon-*/bin/* /usr/bin/ \
&& mv /salmon-*/lib/* /usr/lib/
```

Here is my nextflow pipeline where trying to run a simple command that create an index from a transcriptome using salmon :

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
 
/*
 * The following pipeline parameters specify the reference genomes
 * and read pairs and can be provided as command line options
 */
params.reads = "/nextflow_training/data_subset/SRR11508672_{1,2}.fastq"
params.transcriptome = "/nextflow_training/data/Clownfish/A.percula_final.fasta"
params.outdir = "/nextflow_training/results"
 
workflow { 
    INDEX(params.transcriptome)
}
 
process INDEX {
    tag "$transcriptome.simpleName"
    publishDir params.outdir

    input:
    path transcriptome
 
    output:
    path 'index'
 
    script:
    """
    salmon index --threads 1 -t $transcriptome -i index
    """
}
```

The process seems to start correctly :

```
...

[Step 1 of 4] : counting k-mers
```

but after a while it's stops with out creating my output file (the index)

The error returned is the following :

````
executor >  local (1)
[ee/e6b00e] process > INDEX (A) [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1 ✘
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'INDEX (A)'

Caused by:
  Process `INDEX (A)` terminated with an error exit status (139)

Command executed:

  salmon index --threads 1 -t A.percula_final.fasta -i index

Command exit status:
  139

Command output:
  Threads = 1
  Vertex length = 31
  Hash functions = 5
  ...

Command error:
  qemu: uncaught target signal 11 (Segmentation fault) - core dumped
  .command.sh: line 2:     8 Segmentation fault      salmon index --threads 1 -t A.percula_final.fasta -i index

Work dir:
  /Users/victorcat/nextflow_training/work/ee/e6b00e5bb93ce2f017c9e2242ea0f3

Tip: when you have fixed the problem you can continue the execution adding the option `-resume` to the run command line

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details```
 

Any ideas ? I'm wondering is this is because I'm on a macbook m1 or maybe not enough memory or maybe something incorrect on my nextflow pipeline. I don't understand the error message.

thank for the help !
````

Comment: If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/), both of which deal with bioinformatics.